# Здесь Парень создал CRM по MVC.но он создал Model и новый слой с View, к кнопке but привязал действие с бд это разве считается паттерном MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvc

[image: Архитектура проекта]

[image: Код but]

[image: код кнопки на форме которая вызывает форму где расположена but]

```
Код but
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Customer = new Customer();
            Customer.Name = textBox1.Text;
            Close();
        }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Сильно зависит от того, что считать MVC-паттерном. Когда насмотритесь на -цатую реализацию - будете говорить о семействе MV-паттернов, каждый из которых нацелен на свою конкретную задачу и сможете выбирать более подходящий вариант под ваши цели. Общая задача - просто отделить данные от кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я тут вижу частично MVP(model view presenter) - аналог MVC для winforms